# Declared function can't be found

Tags: c++

i am trying to make a object oriented menu, but i encountered some problems with initialising an int variable with the return of a int function.

Code:

```
#include <Menu.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void Menu::showMainMenu(){
    cout<<"""Main Menu"""<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Manage students"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Manage assignments"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Manage statistics"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Print database"<<endl;
    cout<<"0. Exit"<<endl<<endl;
}


void Menu::showStudentMenu(){
    cout<<"""Student Menu"""<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Add student"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Remove student"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Edit student"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Print student"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Print students"<<endl<<endl;

}


void Menu::showAssignmentMenu(){
    cout<<"""Assignment Menu"""<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Add assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Remove assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Edit assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Print assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Print assignments"<<endl<<endl;
}



void Menu::showStatisticsMenu(){
    cout<<"""Assignment Menu"""<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Add assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Remove assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Edit assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Print assignment"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Print assignments"<<endl<<endl;
}




string Menu::stringInputHandler(){
    string input;
    cout<<"enter:";  cin>>input; cout<<endl;

    if(!input.empty()){
        return input;
    }

    cout<<"Input cannot be empty"<<endl;
    stringInputHandler();
return "Error! (f:sIH)";
}

int intInputHandler(){
    int input;
    cout<<"enter:";  cin>>input; cout<<endl;

    if(input){
        return input;
    }

    cout<<"Input cannot be empty"<<endl;
    intInputHandler();
    return 0;
}


void Menu::CommandControllMain(){
    showMainMenu();
    int ret;
    ret = intInputHandler();

    while(ret){
        switch(ret){
        case 1:CommandControllStudent();break;
        case 2:CommandControllAssignment();break;
        case 3:break;
        case 4:break;
        case 0:break;
        default:cout<<"Wrong option selected!";break;
        }
    } 
}



void Menu::CommandControllStudent(){
    showStudentMenu();
    int ret = intInputHandler();


}



void Menu::CommandControllAssignment(){
    showAssignmentMenu();
    int ret =intInputHandler();

}

void Menu::CommandControllStatistics(){
    showStatisticsMenu();
    int ret =intInputHandler();

}
```

so there is: `intInputHandler()` and a var `int ret` and i cant do int ret = intInputHandler();

ERROR:

```
D:\c++\Begin\Lab6-8_UML\Debug/../Menu.cpp:121: undefined reference to `Menu::intInputHandler()'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
int intInputHandler()
```

with

```
int Menu::intInputHandler()
```

You're not implementing the member, but a free function.

Comment: @Bogdan: Also note that the logic is broken in that function. An int cannot be *empty*, and if the initial input is 0 then you recursively call the function and ignore the result.

Comment: Yup, didn't even look inside the function... :)

Comment: Thank you, i seen the problem afterwards :P